# Joining (concat) list of similar dataframes in geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a list of dataframes, all of the same structure and all are polygons.

How can I add them all together using geopandas?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

it seems that this is the right way to do that right now:

```
rdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame( pd.concat( dataframesList, ignore_index=True) )
```

Comment: Great answer, one improvement:

`rdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat(dataframesList, ignore_index=True), crs=dataframesList[0].crs)`.

Now new dataframe will also have the same CRS as one of the initial dataframes. Because of using `pandas.concat` any geographical metadata such as CRS does not get preserved by default.

Comment: This works well - thanks. I did find the append can go astray e.g. when one file has "name" and another has "Name", I ended up with nothing in either column for rows from one file.  I couldn't reproduce it reliably so I ended up forcing column names to lower case to simplify the column mashing, which seems to be reliable.

Comment: I ought you a beer! Thanks Phillipp_Kats

Comment: @AleksMat Is there any other geographical metadata besides CRS that we should also copy over to make sure it is preserved?

Comment: @rasen58 According to [GeoDataFrame implementation](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/v0.8.1/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L82) it seems that the only other metadata information is geometry column name. In a rare case that you don't use the default name "geometry" then you have to consolidate that as well.

Answer (score 32):

I just experimented with this - maybe in GeoPandas 0.2.1 and Pandas 0.20.3 it is a bit more concise:

```
gdf = pd.concat([gdf1, gdf2])
```

gdf is automatically created as a GeoDataFrame. Of course if there is a chance of conflicting indices you'll want to keep the 'ignore_index=True' parameter.

Comment: I just tried this and I can confirm it does not work (using pandas_0.20.3 geopandas_0.3.0).  
The result is a DataFrame, not a GeoDataFrame.  
E.g. if you try to use `gdf1.to_file(xxx, driver='ESRI Shapefile')` you will get an error which says `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file'`

Comment: @jberrio thanks for the update! looks like the update to GeoPandas made things more explicit.

Comment: For the flagger that requested moderators remove the Accept checkmark please be aware that this is not possible to do.  As a workaround from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187263/215590 I tried deleting the answer, but the answerer requested that it be undeleted.  A long term solution for dealing with accepted answers that may no longer be correct has been proposed at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/keeping-special-status-for-accepted-answers-without-sticking-them-to-top-forever

Comment: This worked fine for me with pandas version: 0.24.2 and geopandas version: 0.5.0

Comment: this works for me, the output type is a geodataframe. Using python 3.8.3; pandas 1.0.5; geopandas 0.8.0.