# Create a function that will return geodataframe

Tags: python, python-3, function, field-mapping, geodataframe

I have created the following function to take Origin = str, Destination = str, line = shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString, node = GeoDataFrame

```py
def create_lines_df(Origin, Destination, line_, nodes_):
    line_dfs = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
    dict_ = [{'Origin':Origin,'Destination':Destination,'geometry':line_,
                         'length':line_.length,
                       'osmid':[nodes_.index.values]}]

    df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict_, geometry='geometry', crs=oslo_edges_proj.crs)
    line_dfs = line_dfs.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

and the goal is to return a geodataframe  but the result geodataframe is empty, although when I change line_dfs to a list it does correctly return the result I want but in a list.

What do I need to change?

Edited the above code to be:

```
gamle_dfs = []
def create_lines_df_2(Origin, Destination, line_, nodes_):


dict_ = [{'Origin':Origin,'Destination':Destination,'geometry':line_,
                     'length':line_.length,
                   'osmid':[nodes_.index.values]}]

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict_, geometry='geometry', crs=oslo_edges_proj.crs)
gamle_dfs.append(df)
```

Now I have a list of dataframes that I can't extract.
Any recommendations?

Comment: You're not returning anything from your functions and you seem to be using global vars (bad practice) but not declaring them as global.  Are you calling this function multiple times to try and build up a gdf iteratively?

Comment: I am calling this function for each origin-destination couple, about 15 times for each district, as I need each district LineStrings together in 1 dataframe, any suggestions?

Comment: @user2856 yes this is what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad practice to modify globals inside your function and your function doesn't `return` anything.

1. **Inside** your function, just create a single dataframe for the curent origin-destination couple and **return** it, i.e `return df`.
2. **Outside** your function, append returned origin-destination couple DFs into a list (do not modify this list in your function) in a loop or using list comprehension.
3. Concatenate the list of DFs, i.e [`df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat(list_of_dfs, ignore_index=True))`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/162661/2856)

You should also add a `crs` argument to your function and pass in `oslo_edges_proj.crs` rather than relying on a global (again, globals are bad ok)

Comment: Thank you, so much