# Python geopandas - replace append with concat

Tags: python, geopandas

Python-beginner here. I'm trying to fix a deprecation warning in:

```py
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['location', 'geometry'])
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(StartDir):
    for fname in files:
        if fname.endswith(".tif"):
            df = df.append({'location': fname, 'geometry': getBounds(os.path.join(dir+"/", fname))}, ignore_index=True)
```

by replacing the append line with:

```py
df = gpd.pd.concat(df,{'location': fname, 'geometry': getBounds(os.path.join(dir+"/", fname))}, ignore_index=True)
```

which leads to this error message:

`TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "GeoDataFrame"`

What am I missing?

Comment: `concat` is expecting a list of (geo)dataframes as the first argument. See [the docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html) about creating a GeoDataframe from your data. This [GIS SE thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/162659/128665) might also be useful.

Comment: Please note the "Python-beginner here" in my question. I'm still struggling especially with data types and their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `concat` to work, it needs a list of dataframes. You can make a temporary dataframe in each iteration of your loop using the dictionary notation `{}` you already have, but by passing it to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor, like so:

```py
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['location', 'geometry'])
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(StartDir):
    for fname in files:
        if fname.endswith(".tif"):

            # create a temporary df with the desired values, it necessary to specify the index
            df_to_append = gpd.pd.DataFrame({'location': fname, 'geometry': getBounds(os.path.join(dir+"/", fname))}, index=[0])
            
            # here the temporary dataframe is appended to the original dataframe each iteration of the loop
            # by passing a list [] of the orignal dataframe and the temporary one to `pd.concat()`  
            # importantly, the index is now ignored to renumber each row sequentially
            df = gpd.pd.concat([df, df_to_append], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I think, I understand it also. The main point seems to be that Python or the library does not understand that the object is a DataFrame without creating an object of the type DataFrame and assigning the data to it. Is that a Python thing or specific to the library?